# Issue at implementing overlay hover on image cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Yesterday I was struggling to solve a tracking problem: they are applied to implement a code on w3schools care through, at hover to appear a background on a bootstrap card. Unfortunately, when I place the mouse anywhere on that line, an overlay is triggered. I would like to trigger only in the card area and I cannot solve it.

HTML:

```
<section class="bgimage">
<div class="container-item ">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="hovereffect">
      <div class="card shadow" style="width: 20rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="images/popit/item1.png" alt="1">

      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <div class="overlay-item">
          <h5 class="card-title">Design</h5>
          <p class="card-text">TEST</p>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS(From W3Schools):

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Screenshot with issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAW3E.jpg

Thank you so much!

Comment: Give us the w3school link.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You make hover effect on `container` with this code `container:hover` but there is no `container` class in your code.
2. Hovering `overlay` class but there is no `overlay` class in your code. Take a close look.
3. One missed ending `div` what the @Loïc Monard told.

Solution:

Create a hover effect on just `card`

```
.card:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

`overlay-item` will be `overlay`

I think you will get your desired result. Read through the article. You will understand.

Answer (score 1):

one closing div tag `</div>` is missing, make sure to indent properly your code to prevent this kind of mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have container and overlay classes in your html and a div tag is missing from the bottom too.